# How can I make a cube hollow on the inside?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

In general I wanted to make it in unity3d but I saw that in tutorials, they made it in blender.

This is what I did in unity:

[image: Cube]

I want to make this high cube hollow on the inside, and make a small door so that I will be able to walk inside the cube. Later on, I want to somehow add stairs but the problem now is how to make it hollow on the inside.

I saw in some places the suggestion to use blender so I tried this tutorial in blender:

[Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOH6rCJ390E)

But got stuck there after I checked the Add Mesh Extra Objects and clicked on Save User Settings. I tried then to click on the bottom on Add > Mesh but then I don't have Extra Objects. I have Extras objects like in the tutorial video.

Anyone my main goal is to make the high cube hollow on the inside with a small door on the bottom so I will be able to walk inside.

Comment: Usually this is done in modelling tools like blender or Maya but If you want to do this in Unity use this free asset : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11919

Answer (score 1):

From what I know Unity3D has no 3DModelling by default (maybe there is something for that in store), so you need to use Blender or some other program (for example Maya). There is https://blender.stackexchange.com/ where you can ask same question (since it is not really unity3d related)

Maybe this will be helpful : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5849/how-do-i-create-a-solid-object-cube

Overall what you could do, but it is not the est way - you can build a everything out of boxes yourself in Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

Try use to boolean modifier. Take a look this tutorial:

[Blender 2.6 Tutorial 26 - Boolean Modifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDweCpDAB_o)